# Function Signatures/Interfaces from Pybind11 Module (IDE Suggestions)

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, pybind11, python-3.10, function-signature

Let's assume we have a simple module called `_sample` built with [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11):

```cpp
/* py_bindings.cpp */
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(_sample, m) {
    m.def("add", [](int a, int b) { return a + b; });
    m.def("add", [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) { return lhs + rhs; });
}
```

This produces a dynamic module file `_sample.pyd` (Windows) or `_sample.so` (Linux), which we can then import in the actual module `sample`:

```py
## sample\__init__.py ##
from ._sample import *
```

So that we can write:

```py
## script.py ##
import sample as s

print(s.add(4, 2))       # 6
print(s.add('AB', 'C'))  # ABC
```

The above code works fine, but the **IDE does not know which functions are included** in `_sample` until the code is actually run. And as a result, there are no function suggestions at all (and no function signature suggestions either).

[image]

As I would like to help the users of my library, my question is: **how do I include function suggestions (or "function hints") in my module?**

I've tried including the below code in `sample\__init__.py` as I thought the `...` might work as a "hint". But unfortunately, this overrides the original `add` function from `_sample`.

```py
def add(arg0: int, arg1: int) -> int:
    ...
```

Are there ways to **hint** the function signatures to a **Python IDE**?

*Of course, I want to extend this to classes, class functions & module attributes too. I just picked functions as a starting point.*

Comment: This depends on your IDE, but maybe try to look into https://github.com/sizmailov/pybind11-stubgen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a stub or interface (pyi) file. The IDE can understand the signature of functions and classes from this file.
If you're using pybind11, check out *pybind11-stubgen* for automatic generation of a stub file.